# What kinds of demonstrable problems occur when subclassing Ruby Built ins?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider Ruby code like

```
class Row < Hash
   def count_of_columns
      self.keys.length
   end
end

c['Col 1'] = 1
c['Col 2'] = 2
puts c.count_of_columns 
# 2
```

and JavaScript code like this:

```
function Row() {}
Row.prototype.column_count = function() { 
  return Object.keys(this).length
}


class Row {  // has Object as prototype
  column_count() { 
    return Object.keys(this).length
  }
}
```

Despite the similarity of how these objects are used in the two distinct languages, why is it is said that subclassing ruby builtins is tricky? I've seen some design considerations mentioned in 'Beware Subclassing Ruby Builtins', which if you're not branching on runtime type in your program, you may not have those problems.

Are there any other reasons people share for why you don't derive directly from built-ins in Ruby? Something specific.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subclass a built-in, you start assuming that your subclass acts like the built-in, but when the built-in would return another instance of the built-in, you expect it to return another instance of your subclass.  But this will only happen if you've thought about this situation ahead of time and defined the methods.  The more methods you tack on to deal with this case, the more you might expect your subclass to take, leading to an ever-growing list of methods you reimplement in your subclass.

For example, consider your Row implementation.  What do you expect to happen when you call `#select` on your row? Should it return back another instance of `Row`? If you want that behavior, then you need to implement it.  But if you get that behavior, then maybe you'd expect `#reject` to also return instances of `Row`, and ... and ... and... (though see comments, sometimes you do get your expected instance!)

I think in general, a better solution would be to use the built-in as your 'data' and some domain concept that holds the data with the appropriate methods.  Don't let outsiders manipulate your data.

For further reading, you can look into why Rails 5 transitioned their ActionController::Parameters from inheriting from Hash to being an independent object that holds a Hash.  I couldn't find a helpful link that described everything involved, so [here's](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14384) one of the initial pull requests with discussion.

Comment: Ruby 2.2.1 Behaves contrary to what you state. merge, keep_if etc on an instance of Row, return instances whose .class as Row, there is not that class reversion happening that you said I'd need to implement - different in your Ruby version?

Comment: In both languages, each instance has a reference to its class|prototype. As long as instances created from it preserve that field, which they appear to do in my Ruby 2.2.1 tests with merge and keep_if, I can't reproduce that behavior.

Comment: I'm surprised merge returned a `Row`, but upon checking you're right.  `reject` and `select` has the tricky behavior I mentioned.  I'll edit.

Comment: Oh my - reject is broken - even if you dont reject any you get a different instance, and it loses the class. Thanks @mickey-shiu